# Visual Studio 2008 Source Control Explorer with Subversion

Tags: visual-studio, svn, version-control, source-control-explorer

I usually use Visual Studio Team System 2008 Source Control Explorer with TFS, but I'm considering using Subversion for some small projects, can I make use of the already installed Source Control Explorer without installing a new Subversion client/plugin in my IDE?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think you can use the Source Control Explorer (I guess this is something related to TFS?).

But you have several options to integrate subversion into Visual Studio:

- [AnkhSVN plugin](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) (free)
- [Mindscape File Explorer](http://www.mindscape.co.nz/blog/?p=199) + [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) (free)
- [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/) (commercial)

I'm using mostly TortoiseSVN (as a stand-alone subversion client).

I have also installed AnkhSVN, because it allows me to see which files are modified inside visual studio, but other than that, I really don't need any integrated Visual Studio solution for source control.

Comment: Correct - the Source Control Explorer is UI provided by the Team Foundation Server IDE integration into Visual Studio.  It talks directly to Team Foundation Server using the TFS .NET API and is not a pluggable for different version control systems such as SVN.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install a new Subversion client/plugin to the IDE.

Have a look at [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/). It's not free but it is reasonably priced and very good.